# PCL: How to extract cluster label from k-means clustering in PCL 1.8.1?

Tags: c++, k-means, point-cloud-library

I would like to use the k-means clustering algorithm to extract labels for my points in PCL 1.8.1. According to the [docs](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.8.1/classpcl_1_1_kmeans.html), there is a protected attribute PointsToClusters. 
Any ideas on how to access this attribute or how to extract the clusters otherwise?

Thank you!

```cpp
pcl::Kmeans real(static_cast<int> (cloud->points.size()), 3);
real.setClusterSize(nominalClusterNumber);
for (size_t i = 0; i < cloud->points.size(); i++)
    {
        std::vector<float> data(3);
        data[0] = cloud->points[i].x;
        data[1] = cloud->points[i].y;
        data[2] = cloud->points[i].z;
        real.addDataPoint(data);
    }
real.kMeans();
```

Comment: It's not C++ that'll help you here. It's `PCL`.. Make that community your primary target. I'd like to see where this goes though because I like it, but I can't help you I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested - it's pretty easy. Provided the centroids by PCL, you already have the answer. Simply compute for each point the distance to all centroids and label them according to the closest centroid. That's how [KMeans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) works.